# Laravel middleware on logout route - ERASE browser's cache via HTTP protocol

Tags: laravel, http

> **TL;DR:** Function is proper. I still need to connect logout route middleware, it doesn't work specifically on logout. `dd()` **is not** be a proper test for middleware, pressing the back button after logout would not work since the cached headers are erased - is the right test.

I am using the following middleware to avoid the browser's back button to send back cache after user logs out, which is a security issue, even though nothing could be done vis a vis server, still sensitive info could be shown.

The function I am using (that stomps multiple times just to make sure cache is dead...)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    return $response->header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
        ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
        ->header('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
}
```

I am trying to connect this as a `$routeMiddleware` in `Http/Kernel.php` and in my `web.php` as follows:

`Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout')->middleware('invalidate');`

Which is not working (still can back to view) so I also tried:

```
Route::middleware(['invalidate'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
});
```

And that also didn't work.

Yet if I register the middleware under `$middlewareGroups`, it works perfect, yet I don't surely know if this function also affects other cache methods that Laravel has, that essentially eases server load and enhances response time, an example for that would be cached User sessions, there are many more out-of-the-box caching that laravel does and moreover many other essential packages used.

Please let me know if it's ok to place it under `$middlewareGroups`, or what i'm doing wrong trailing it after the logout route.\

Thanks

Comment: why aren't you using the normal php way of changing the headers? Looks to me that `$response = $next($request)` isn't going to pick up the response of the logout accordingy.
`header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');`i tried this out and it worked in my case